# OnImageCapturedListener of CameraX gives an error

Tags: android, callback, android-camerax

I am testing the new CameraX API and I have the following line of code:

```
imageCapture.takePicture(executor, object:ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener{
    // do some work when image is captured 
})
```

But the argument `object:ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener` is underlined with red. Android Studio is telling me: `"This type has a constructor and thus must be initialized here"`

Note: The code above is called inside a click listener of a Button.

Below you can see the other listener of `ImageCapture` class which is `OnImageSavedListener`. With this interface I have no errors.

```
findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.capture_button).setOnClickListener {
            val file = File(externalMediaDirs.first(),
                "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg")

            imageCapture.takePicture(file, executor,
                object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener {

                    override fun onError(
                        imageCaptureError: ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError,
                        message: String,
                        exc: Throwable?
                    ) {
                        val msg = "Photo capture failed: $message"
                        Log.e("CameraXApp", msg, exc)
                        viewFinder.post {
                            Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onImageSaved(file: File) {
                        val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: ${file.absolutePath}"
                        Log.d("CameraXApp", msg)
                        viewFinder.post {
                            Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }

                        var bitmap:Bitmap = viewFinder.bitmap
                        runOnUiThread { imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) }
                    }
                })
```

I have no problem with this but when I use `OnImageCapturedListener` and replace the `onImageSaved` callback with the `onCaptureSuccess` callback then I get an error as described above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try out this code.

```
imageCapture.takePicture(executor,object :ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener(){
            override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy?, rotationDegrees: Int) {
                super.onCaptureSuccess(image, rotationDegrees)  

                // capture image 

                }
             override fun onError(
                imageCaptureError: ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError,
                message: String,
                cause: Throwable?) {
                super.onError(imageCaptureError, message, cause)
                // error in capturing
            }

        })
```

Comment: Not working, I get the error: "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

Comment: @ebeninki i made change please check this one is working